# Android sqlLite error - failed to read row 0 column 1 from a cursorwindow?

Tags: android, sql

I am relatively new to Android Development and using SQL lite for development. I'm currently creating an Android application for my Final year project in university and have hit an issue when trying to run my application with a database - failed to read row 0 column 1 from a cursorwindow. I have had a look through some of the questions and answers already posted and have tried some of the answers, but can't get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LtssDyslexiaDb";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_STUDENTS = "student";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String ST_ID = "id";
private static final String ST_FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
private static final String ST_SURNAME = "surname";
private static final String ST_SCHOOL = "school";
private static final String ST_READING_LEVEL = "reading_Level";
private static final String ST_AGE = "age";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STUDENTS + "("
            + ST_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + ST_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + ST_SURNAME + " TEXT" + ST_SCHOOL + " TEXT,"
            + ST_READING_LEVEL + " TEXT" + ST_AGE + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_STUDENTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addStudentProfile(StudentProfile sProfile) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ST_FIRST_NAME, sProfile.getFirstName()); // Contact Name
    //values.put(KEY_PH_NO, sProfile.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_STUDENTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
StudentProfile getStudentProfile(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_STUDENTS, new String[] { ST_ID,
            ST_FIRST_NAME, ST_SURNAME, ST_SCHOOL, ST_READING_LEVEL, ST_AGE}, ST_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    StudentProfile sProfile = new StudentProfile(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));
    // return contact
    return sProfile;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<StudentProfile> getAllContacts() {
    List<StudentProfile> contactList = new ArrayList<StudentProfile>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_STUDENTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            StudentProfile student = new StudentProfile();
            student.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            student.setFirstName(cursor.getString(1));
            student.setSurname(cursor.getString(2));
            student.setSchool(cursor.getString(3));
            student.setReadingLevel(cursor.getString(4));
            student.setAge(cursor.getString(5));

            String name = cursor.getString(1) +" "+ cursor.getString(2);
            MainActivity.ArrayofName.add(name);
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(student);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(StudentProfile sProfile) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put((ST_FIRST_NAME + ST_SURNAME), (sProfile.getFirstName()+sProfile.getSurname()));
    //values.put(KEY_PH_NO, sProfile.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_STUDENTS, values, ST_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(sProfile.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(StudentProfile sProfile) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_STUDENTS, ST_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(sProfile.getID()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_STUDENTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
} }
```

and here is the error message that i am getting:

```
01-30 17:11:53.042: E/CursorWindow(32734): Failed to read row 0, column 4 from a CursorWindow which has 3 rows, 4 columns.
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Failed to read row 0, column 4 from a CursorWindow which has 3 rows, 4 columns
```

It means that you have 4 columns with numbers *0, 1, 2, 3* and you try to get number *5* that doesn't exist.

And now, look to your creation code. You forgot commas after "TEXT"

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STUDENTS + "("
        + ST_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + ST_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
  >>>   + ST_SURNAME + " TEXT" // should to " TEXT, "
        + ST_SCHOOL + " TEXT,"
  >>>   + ST_READING_LEVEL + " TEXT" // should to " TEXT, "
        + ST_AGE + " TEXT" + ")";
db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
```

*P.S. don't forget to uninstall application after changing onCreate code, to install new version*

Comment: or simply update the `DATABASE_VERSION` field to get the `onUpgrade` to be called

Comment: @Kirill Shalnov - Ah wonderful, that's exactly what was wrong, thank you so much!